# Cannot perform close/open ASP.Net Ajax ModalPopupExtenders in sequence from server side code

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I'm having a problem hiding one ModalPopupExtender and Showing another within the same server-side call.

My app requires user input on some validating conditions.  These conditions are evaluated in sequence and when certain conditions are true it requires a user to verify (click yes or no) via a ModalPopupExtender window.  If the user clicks Yes, evaluation should continue and if another condition requires user input it should also open a modal dialog - until all conditions are passed.

I've got no problem if only one of the conditions requires input, but if more than one require input, only the first modal is displayed and I can't figure out why.  When tracing the code it's clear that the Hide() on the first popup is hit and the Show() on the second popup is hit, but the second popup never shows up.

I've tried to pull out the relevant code blocks here with extreme simplification.  It's a really complex project and I may have missed something but I hope it's enough to describe my problem.

Problematic process flow:

1. User clicks "Continue" -> DoContinue is called -> set conditions flags -> Show first modal popup -> Return to user
2. User clicks "Yes" -> calls condition 1 Yes click handler (set handled flag, hide modal popup) -> call DoContinue-> re-evaluate conditions flags -> attempt to show second modal popup -> return to user.

The first popup disappears but the second is never shown.

It's only a problem when Hide() is being called on the first modal in the same request where Show() is being called on the second.

MyContainerControl.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MyContainerControl" %>
 <input Type="Submit"
          id="btnContinue"
          Name="btnContinue"
          Value="Continue"
          OnServerClick="Continue_Click"
          runat="server"/>

<asp:UpdatePanel 
        ID="updateCondition1" 
        runat="server" 
        ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender 
                    ID="modalCondition1" 
                    runat="server" 
                    BehaviorID="dlgCondition1"
                    TargetControlID="btnFakeInvokeModalCondition1" 
                    PopupControlID="divCondition1" 
                    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                    DropShadow="true" 
                    PopupDragHandleControlID="divDragCondition1"
                    RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResize" 
                    CancelControlID="btnCondition1No" />
        <input type="button" 
                        id="btnFakeInvokeModalCondition1" 
                        runat="server" 
                        style="display: none" />
        <div id="divCondition1" 
                runat="server" 
                class="modalPopup">
            <custom:Condition1Control id="condition1" runat="server" visible="false" />
            <div id="divDragCondition1"></div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel 
        ID="updateCondition2" 
        runat="server" 
        ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender 
                    ID="modalCondition2" 
                    runat="server" 
                    BehaviorID="dlgCondition2"
                    TargetControlID="btnFakeInvokeModalCondition2" 
                    PopupControlID="divCondition2" 
                    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                    DropShadow="true" 
                    PopupDragHandleControlID="divDragCondition2"
                    RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResize" 
                    CancelControlID="btnCondition2No" />
        <input type="button" 
                        id="btnFakeInvokeModalCondition2" 
                        runat="server" 
                        style="display: none" />
        <div id="divCondition2" 
                runat="server" 
                class="modalPopup">
            <custom:Condition2Control id="condition2" runat="server" visible="false" />
            <div id="divDragCondition2"></div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

MyContainerControl.cs:

```
public class MyContainerControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected HtmlInputImage btnContinue;

    //Condition1
    protected AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender modalCondition1;
    protected UpdatePanel updateCondition1;
    protected HtmlGenericControl divCondition1;
    protected Condition1Control condition1;

    //Condition2
    protected AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender modalCondition2;
    protected UpdatePanel updateCondition2;
    protected HtmlGenericControl divCondition2;
    protected Condition2Control condition2;        

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        condition1.Condition1RaisedEvent += HandleCondition1Event;
        condition2.Condition2RaisedEvent += HandleCondition2Event;
        btnContinue.ServerClick += btnContinue_ServerClick;
    }

    protected void HandleCondition1Event(object sender, Condition1EventArgs e)
    {
        // use ship to store
        ViewState["Condition1Yes"] = true;
        ViewState["Condition1Value"] = e.Condition1Value;
        modalCondition1.Hide();
        DoContinue(sender);
    }

    protected void HandleCondition2Event(object sender, Condition2EventArgs e)
    {
        // use ship to store
        ViewState["Condition2Yes"] = true;
        ViewState["Condition2Value"] = e.Condition2Value;
        modalCondition2.Hide();
        DoContinue(sender);
    }

    protected void btnContinue_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoContinue(sender);
    }

    protected void DoContinue(object sender)
    {
        // test for conditions - just plug to true for demonstration

        bool throwCondition1 !(ViewState["Condition1Yes"] == null ? false : (bool)ViewState["Condition1Yes"])
        bool throwCondition2 = !(ViewState["Condition2Yes"] == null ? false : (bool)ViewState["Condition2Yes"])

        // analyze conditions

        if (throwCondition1)
        {
            var condition1Yes = ViewState["Condition1Yes"] == null ? false : (bool)ViewState["Condition1Yes"];
            if (!condition1Yes)
            {
                divCondition1.Visible = true;
                modalCondition1.Show();
                return;
            }
        }

        if (throwCondition2)
        {
            var condition2Yes = ViewState["Condition2Yes"] == null ? false : (bool)ViewState["Condition2Yes"];
            if (!condition2Yes)
            {
                divCondition2.Visible = true;
                modalCondition1.Show();
                return;
            }
        }

        // do other work
    }
}
```

Condition1UI.ascx - Condition2UI.ascx is very similar:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Condition1Control" %>
<div id="divCondition1Container" runat="server">        
    <input id="hdnCondition1Value" type="hidden" runat="server" value="<%# this.Condition1Value %>" />
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlCondition1UI" runat="server">
        <br />
        <h2>
            Warning!</h2>
        <hr />
        <br />
        <div>
            <p>Condition1 has been met.</p>
            <br />
            <br />
            <p>Would you like to continue?</p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
    </asp:Panel>
    <div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:Button ID="btnCondition1Yes" runat="server" class="green" Text="Yes" style="padding: 3px 7px;" OnClick="DoCondition1YesClick" OnClientClick="$find('dlgCondition1').hide();" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <button id="btnCondition1No" class="red">No</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
      <br />
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

Condition1Control.cs - Condition2Control.cs is almost identical:

```
public class Condition1EventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Condition1Value { get; set; }
}

public class Condition1Control : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public HtmlInputHidden Condition1Value;

    public event EventHandler<Condition1EventArgs> Condition1RaisedEvent;

    protected virtual void RaiseCondition1Event(Condition1EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<Condition1EventArgs> handler = Condition1RaisedEvent;

        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(this, e);
    }

    public void DoCondition1ButtonYesClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseCondition1Event(new Condition1EventArgs{
            Condition1Value = Condition1Value.Value
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change UpdatePanel's UpdateMode property to "Always" or don't forget to call 'Update' method of UpdatePanel which UI you want to update as result of postback fired from another UpdatePanel. So try to add updateCondition2.Update method call after modalCondition2.Show method in your code.